# Why I can verify static method for 20 times and it doesn't fail?

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

That's my test code:

```java
public void testApplyListWhenAddTheSameIDThenReturnDuplicateEntityException(){
    MyEntity entityRCM = createMyEntity(AGE_ID, WEIGHT_ID, 0L);
    entityModel.addEntity(entityRCM);
    MyEntity entityOPC = createMyEntity(DIFF_AGE_ID, WEIGHT_ID, 0L);
    EntityCreate create = new EntityCreate(entityOPC);
    List<EntityChange> changeList = new ArrayList<EntityChange>();
    changeList.add(create);
    try {
        entityModel.apply(changeList);
        fail();
    }catch(DuplicateEntityException e) {
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(times(20));
        LogManager.error(Mockito.<Logger>anyObject(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.<DuplicateEntityException>anyObject());
    }
}
```

The problem is here:

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(times(20));
LogManager.error(Mockito.<Logger>anyObject(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.<DuplicateEntityException>anyObject());
```

I want to verify a static method `error` in class `LogManager`, but how can I verify this method for twenty times but it doesn't fail.

Comment: Did you add [`@PrepareForTest` and `mockStatic`](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#Mocking_Static_Method)? If not, then you may have set up your matchers and static call but PowerMock never sees the actual call to mock before your test completes.

Comment: yes,Thank you.I have solved this problem with adding mockStatic(LogManager.class).And that's what you say "never sees the actual call to mock",I have tried to verifyStatic() without having mockStatic()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in the comments:

> Did you add [`@PrepareForTest` and `mockStatic`](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#Mocking_Static_Method)? If not, then you may have set up your matchers and static call but PowerMock never sees the actual call to mock before your test completes.

For context, PowerMock mocks static classes by intercepting the classloader and loading a *replacement* class that calls PowerMock-provided implementations instead of the originals. Unless you add the right preparation, PowerMock won't replace the class, so it won't count static method calls or identify the method to verify, and the test will complete before the verification call ever actually happens.